# How to make radio button validations in AgularJS

Tags: angularjs, validation

I am beginner in AngularJS and i am trying to display bootstrap error validations in AngularJS using below code i am facing two issues

1) Using below code radio group error message is not display i am really not understand why its not working

2)My second problem is phone number is required only when i select phone number radio button other wise its not required how can i do this?

Can some one help me please

### code

```
<form name="studentForm" ng-submit="saveEmployee()" role="form" novalidate>

    <div class="panel panel-primary">

        <div class="panel-heading">
            <h3 class="panel-title">Welcome</h3>
        </div>

        <div class="panel-body">

 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': studentForm.phoneNumber.$touched && studentForm.phoneNumber.$invalid,
            'has-success': studentForm.phoneNumber.$valid }">
                <label for="phoneNumber" class="control-label">Phone Number</label>
                <input type="text" id="phoneNumber" name="phoneNumber" ng-model="employee.phoneNumber" class="form-control"
                    required>
                <span class="help-block" ng-if="studentForm.phoneNumber.$touched && studentForm.phoneNumber.$invalid">
                    Phone Number is required
                </span>
            </div>

 <div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': studentForm.contactPreference.$touched && studentForm.contactPreference.$invalid,
            'has-success': studentForm.contactPreference.$valid }">
                <label for="gender" class="control-label">Contact Preference</label>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="contactPreference" ng-model="employee.contactPreference" value="email"
                            required>
                        Email
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="contactPreference" ng-model="employee.contactPreference" value="phone"
                            required>
                        Phone Number
                    </label>
                </div>
                <span class="help-block" ng-if="studentForm.contactPreference.$touched && studentForm.contactPreference.$invalid">
                    Cintact preference is required
                </span>
            </div>
    </div>
</div>
</form>
```

Comment: What is your controller code? please create snippet if possible

Comment: i think for doing only validations controller code not required

Comment: If required please suggest me with code

Comment: @just code dont you have idea?

Answer (score 0):

Just use required="!employee.contactPreference"

```
<div class="form-group" ng-class="{'has-error': studentForm.contactPreference.$touched && studentForm.contactPreference.$invalid,
            'has-success': studentForm.contactPreference.$valid }">
                <label for="gender" class="control-label">Contact Preference</label>
                <div class="form-control">
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="contactPreference" ng-model="employee.contactPreference" value="email" ng-required="!employee.contactPreference">
                        Email
                    </label>
                    <label class="radio-inline">
                        <input type="radio" name="contactPreference" ng-model="employee.contactPreference" value="phone" ng-required="!employee.contactPreference">
                        Phone Number
                    </label>
                </div>
```